# MatchCollection Result Not Consistent

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, match

I'm getting inconsistent/error results for a Regex MatchCollection using C#;

In my first example, the MatchCollection works. Here is the code that works.

```
 string temp1 = "<td nowrap CLASS=\"sportPicksBorderL2\" style=\"width: 150px;\">&nbsp;\n<B>deGrom, J</B>&nbsp;\n</td>";
            Match inputa = Regex.Match(temp1, @"<B>(.*?)</B>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            MatchCollection inputb = Regex.Matches(temp1, @"<B>(.*?)</B>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            string result1 = inputb[0].Groups[1].Value.ToString(); // Value="deGrom, J"
```

It finds and formats the correct result:  "deGrom,J".

But when I used a very similar input, I get an error "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException".  Here is the code for the code that does not work.

```
string temp2 = "<td nowrap CLASS=\"sportPicksBorderL\">&nbsp;\n<B>\nScherzer, M \n</B>&nbsp;\n</td>";
            Match  inputc= Regex.Match(temp2, @"<B>(.*?)</B>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            MatchCollection inputd = Regex.Matches(temp2, @"<B>(.*?)</B>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            string result2 = inputd[0].Groups[1].Value.ToString();
```

Here is the full error code:
// System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
// HResult = 0x80131502
// Message = Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
//Parameter name: i

What is the correct regex pattern to use?  Is the  tag handled differently?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it because the second string has a newline `\n` you need add option `RegexOptions.Singleline`

```
string temp2 = "<td nowrap CLASS=\"sportPicksBorderL\">&nbsp;\n<B>\nScherzer, M \n</B>&nbsp;\n</td>";
Match  inputc= Regex.Match(temp2, @"<B>(.*?)</B>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
MatchCollection inputd = Regex.Matches(temp2, @"<B>(.*?)</B>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
string result2 = inputd[0].Groups[1].Value.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(result2);
```

Comment: uingtea,  BINGO!! That's the ticket..:)  Works correctly now.